# Problems when using dict comprehensions. NameError: global name is not defined

Tags: python, shell, dictionary, namespaces, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a dict with key as `name` and value as corresponding `User` object.

I am using Python shell from Django shell wrapper `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> names = ['carl', 'jim', 'jack', 'john', 'mark']
# Now using some dict comprehension
>>> u = {name: User.objects.get(username=name) for name in names}
NameError: global name 'User' is not defined
```

However, this works for me:

```
u = {}
for name in names:
    u[name] = User.objects.get(username=name)
```

And I get the desired output, which is:

```
{ 
  'carl': <User: carl>,
  'jack': <User: jack>,
  'jim' : <User: jim>,
  'john': <User: john>,
  'mark': <User: mark>
}
```

I know, there are other ways to accomplish this, but I am curious why are the dict comprehensions not working here.

Any tips?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't see any issue like that, you might be missing something!

Comment: Might be that the dictionary closure isn't getting access to the same namespace as the shell. Does `U = User; u = {name: U.objects.get(username=name) for name in names}` make any difference? (just wondering if this is a bug)

Comment: @Rohan , what are the steps you are following ?
@Dunes , no that doesn't work either, I get `NameError: global name 'U' is not defined`

Comment: @DhruvBaldawa, this is what I tried. `>>> type(User)
<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>
>>> u = {name: User.objects.get(username=name) for name in names}
>>> u
{'admin': <User: admin>, 'u1': <User: u1>}
>>> 
`

Comment: is there problem IPython-specific, let me try it out on default shell

Comment: Try with ./manage.py shell --plain, I already had the same kind of import problems.

Comment: Yes, it works with --plain, then this seems to be a IPython-specific problem. I will file a bug report in their project ! Thanks :-)

Comment: Issue filed at: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2532

Answer (score 2):

I believe [python's issue tracer](http://bugs.python.org/issue13557) is the best answer for you.

In short: it won't work in shell. The same applies to function definition in shell. The imports are unaccesible there.

In regard for your problem I advise:

```
names = [...]
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=names)
name_to_user = {user.username: user for user in users}
```

It does one sql query instead of `len(names)`.

Comment: Yes, I know that is a way to do it, but my problem was not optimization, but comprehension :-)